# MEAN stack display image stored using muller

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am using a MEAN stack for my web application. I am successfully able to store multiple image files on node server and save its path in MongoDB with other information. When I make get request to retrieve the data. How can I send both the image file array and other information back to client?

What is stored in Database is

```
[
  {
    "paintingFileLocations": [
      {
        "fieldname": "artFileLocations",
        "originalname": "logo1.png",
        "encoding": "7bit",
        "mimetype": "image/png",
        "destination": "artImages/paintings",
        "filename": "painting&1619496101680&logo1.png",
        "path": "artImages/paintings/painting&1619496101680&logo1.png",
        "size": 95523
      },
      {
        "fieldname": "artFileLocations",
        "originalname": "logo2.png",
        "encoding": "7bit",
        "mimetype": "image/png",
        "destination": "artImages/paintings",
        "filename": "painting&1619496101684&logo2.png",
        "path": "artImages/paintings/painting&1619496101684&logo2.png",
        "size": 94132
      }
    ],
    "paintingName": "Painting 1",
  }
]
```

This is my get request

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Paintings.find({})
        .then(paintings => { res.send(paintings) })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are using NodeJS for this...
What you will have something is

```
app.post('/route', (req, res, next) => {
  ...
  //code to upload the image
  ...

  // fetch this object from MongoDB
  const object = Model.find('---');

  // here return the object in the response
  res.status(200).send(object)
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what is happening here. I am trying to do a get request and then want to send image files and additional data (paintingName) both to client. Added some more information in the question